# How to synchronize progress in tv series without spoiling

Tags: algorithms

I assume this is a common real life problem. You want to know who has gotten farthest in a tv series without spoiling your conversation partner and also not risk getting spoiled yourself. No one knows the season/episode number of their last episode. What would be the best algorithm for solving this problem?

To make it easier to formulate as a mathematical problem we assume:

- Each person will know if they have watched a major event in the tv series
- Each person will know for sure if a major event is the last major event they have seen in the series

I have not been able to think of anything better than the trivial linear algorithm to this problem. But a proof that nothing better exists would be nice.

Further, it would be nice to add some real life available resources to the problem and see if we manage to get faster solutions. If a third person who have watched all the seasons is available the problem gets trivial. But what if a third person who have not watched the series at all is available, and he does not mind getting spoiled. Other suggestions to tools we can use to solve this are welcome. Is this problem similar to more known problems?

Comment: If the third person doesn't mind spoilers, just have person 1 and 2 tell him everything, and he compares their storyline. Done.

Comment: But that is linear, we want something better:)